# Crystal Reports Data disappearing

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am currently designing a report in crystal reports.
In the header I have the standard fields like Date/Time and a bunch of variables. In some cases one of the variables does not resolve to anything (it is empty).
When that variable is empty all the report data disappears.

I tried tricking Crystal Reports with creating a formular field, but again no luck!

Any ideas?

All data is received from a MySQL database and the field that causes the trouble is based on a custom query (command).

The actual query:

```
SELECT `teacher_name` 
FROM `class_schedule` 
LEFT JOIN (`teacher`, `cs_class`) 
ON (`class_schedule`.`class_supporter`=`teacher`.`teacher_id` AND
    `cs_class`.`cs_id`=`class_schedule`.`cs_id`)
WHERE `class_id`={?classId}
```

Comment: You have some selection criteria on that variable probably. Note that field value can be "null" sometimes - this need different processing than "" (empty).

Comment: I already checked that. The whole query is not even linked to any of the other data :(

Comment: @Ben: How does this variable get set? It may be that whatever is causing it to be set as empty is also causing the report to return no data.

Comment: @Ben Please show us the query.

Comment: I posted the query above. I have quite a lot of confidence in my SQL queries, but I'm just not sure how CR is evaluating it in regards with the report. Running the query alone gives the correct result...

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with MySQL much at all.  That said, I have never seen that construct for LOJs, so I am questioning the format.  Pardon my ignorance if I am uninformed.

If you have CR Developer available, it might be interesting to see what query CR comes up with, and I guess a trace will show what is actually submitted to MySQL.

```
SELECT `teacher_name` 
FROM `class_schedule` cs
  LEFT outer JOIN `teacher` tch
    on `cs`.`class_supporter`=`tch`.`teacher_id` 
  Left outer join `cs_class` csc
    on `csc`.`cs_id`=`cs`.`cs_id`
WHERE `class_id`={?classId}
```

is the best I can recommend trying.